# Migration of data from MsAccess to MS SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access

I have a data in MS Access which I want to migrate into MS SQL. Data stored is in foreign language not in english. I can read data in Access as I have stored regarding font in C:\Windows\Fonts.

I have migrated Access database into MSSQL by in built functionality of MS SQL, but I can not read(data stored in wierd character) this data directly in MS SQL and in .Net web application also.

Can any one suggest me please?

Comment: Have you made sure that your MS SQL uses UTF-8 as its character set?

Comment: use SSIS to migrate the data.

Comment: What data type is the column in SQL Server - is it NVARCHAR? Please expand on 'can not read'. Do you get an error? wierd characters?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Column types are nvarchar. and also characters are wierd

Comment: I suggest you use the `UNICODE` function to inspect the first character of the data in the field. It's possible the data uploaded correctly but none of your clients can display it. `UNICODE` will tell you if the character in the field is indeed the correct unicode character.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps described in official MS support:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/237980
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx

You need to use import wizard and test the columns as you go.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the upsizing wizard within the Access database. The instructions are here:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Move-Access-data-to-a-SQL-Server-database-by-using-the-Upsizing-Wizard-5d74c0df-c8cd-4867-8d07-e6e759d72924

The wizards do not move everything though:

https://blogs.office.com/2012/02/17/five-common-pitfalls-when-upgrading-access-to-sql-server-2/

Edit:

You could use the wizards to create a new sql server db, that way the encoding & collation is done automatically.